# Compile Ben Gottlieb's Twitter oAuth iPhone Library for 4.0 AND 3.1.X

Tags: iphone, ios, compilation, mgtwitterengine

I need Ben Gottlieb's Twitter Engine running on both iOS 4.0 and 3.1.X - I tried to recompile the libOAuth.a Library with certain SDK Versions but I didn't got it to work.
The Library compiled with 3.1.3 SDK works just on 3.1.3 SDK, and the 4.0 compiled Library only on the 4.0 SDK.

Any ideas how to get the Library running on both SDK Versions?

Thanks,
Lukas

Comment: Where are you getting the source code from?

Answer (score 0):

libOAuth is just compiled from the oAuthConsumer project. You should get the source code from oAuthConsumer and the source code into your project, then you can build your project with whatever sdk you want.

I have a project that builds on top of MGTwitterEngine and oAuthConsumer, that adds support for oAuth and the streaming api. The project includes a demo that uses oAuth for login and streams tweets to a table view. You can check it out here https://github.com/TimShi/TSTwitterEngine